# Cyclic Barrier Exception Handling

Tags: java, multithreading

I am facing an issue with Cyclic barrier, please look in to the code below -

MeetingPoint1.java

```
public class MeetingPoint1 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" MeetingPoint1 one cleared... ");
    }

}
```

MeetingPoint2.java

```
public class MeetingPoint2 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(" MeetingPoint Two cleared... ");
    }

}
```

VehicalRunnable.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

/**
 * @author chouhan_r
 *
 */
public class VehicleRunnable implements Runnable {

    private CyclicBarrier barrier1; 
    private CyclicBarrier barrier2;

    public VehicleRunnable(CyclicBarrier barrier1, CyclicBarrier barrier2) {
        this.barrier1 = barrier1;
        this.barrier2 = barrier2;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" Waiting at Meeting Point 1");
            if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Car")){
                throw new RuntimeException("something weird happened");
            }
            barrier1.await();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" Waiting at Meeting Point 2");
            barrier2.await();

        } catch(BrokenBarrierException | RuntimeException | InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

CyclicBarrierMain.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

/**
 * @author chouhan_r
 *
 */
public class CyclicBarrierMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeetingPoint1 meetingPoint1 = new MeetingPoint1();
        MeetingPoint2 meetingPoint2 = new MeetingPoint2();

        CyclicBarrier barrier1 = new CyclicBarrier(3, meetingPoint1);
        CyclicBarrier barrier2 = new CyclicBarrier(3, meetingPoint2);

        VehicleRunnable car = new VehicleRunnable(barrier1, barrier2);
        VehicleRunnable bike = new VehicleRunnable(barrier1, barrier2);
        VehicleRunnable bus= new VehicleRunnable(barrier1, barrier2);
        new Thread(car,"Car").start();
        new Thread(bike,"Bike").start();
        new Thread(bus,"Bus").start();
    }

}
```

When the thread throws some exception all other threads wait at the barrier1 is there any way to run the waiting threads till barrier2 ?? Is it a better Idea to put the barrier.await() method inside the finally block ??

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a cyclic barrier with counter 3. Two of the thread was able to call barrier1.await(); and hence waiting for the counter to be zero so that they can proceed further but the third thread is not able to call barrier1.await(), because you have explicitly throwing the exception before it can call barrier.await(). Hence the counter will not be zero and all other thread will be stuck at the barrier1.await().

If you want to let all other thread to proceed further, you have to call barrier.await() again some where like within this block before throwing the exception.

```
 if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Car")){
                barrier1.await(); // call here
                throw new RuntimeException("something weird happened");
   }
```

Comment: Here I am explicitly throwing exception but what if some code throws exception due to some weird condition.

Comment: Thats what i said..as a programmer you have to aware of all these facts that how barrier.awaits() methods work. You have to make sure that if there is a possibility of throwing exception so that the instruction barrier1.await() skips how you are going to handle. I think using proper exception handling mechanism and knowing the circumstances in advance can only help you. Best of Luck.

Comment: Is it a better idea to put the await() call in finally block ?? because it may be possible that we have multiple await calls.

Comment: It depends upon your application logic. If all the threads has to perform step by step with out any error which can't be handle , exiting the process might be best other wise if you want to continue with your threads even if there is some exception you can put your await() call in finally{} block. It totally depends upon your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using the timeout version of the await. If one of the threads are blocked for a very long time; then this gives a chance for all the barriers to exit.

```
try {
   leader = barrier.await(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // waits for 10 millis - throws exception if timed out or throws BarrierBrokenExcepion if Barrier is Broker
} catch (TimeoutException e) {

  if (barrier.isBroken()) { //on timeout checks if barrier is broken and exits
    System.out.println("BARRIER is broken "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    break;
  }

} catch (BrokenBarrierException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   break;
}
```

You could also call reset() on the thread where the barrier was missed / threw an Exception. This will cause the an BarrierBrokenException on the other two hanging threads. The rest is implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Latch or Semaphore instead of Barrier. Simply Barrier is to synchronize multiple threads, Latch is for synchronizing events.